# If $f(x)=\log \left(\cfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ for $-1 < x < 1$,then find $f \left(\cfrac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}\right)$ in terms of $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, logarithms

> If $f(x)=\log \left(\cfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ for $-1 < x < 1$,then
>   find $f \left(\cfrac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}\right)$ in terms of $f(x)$.

**My Attempt**
$$f \left(\cfrac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}\right)=\log\left(\cfrac{1+\cfrac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}{1-\cfrac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}\right)=\log \left(\cfrac{1+3x^2+3x+x^3}{1+3x^2-3x-x^3}\right)=\\\log(1+3x^2+3x+x^3)-\log(1+3x^2-3x-x^3)$$

Now I am kinda clueless about how to express this in terms of $f(x)$.

Can you guys help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log(1+3x^2+3x+x^3)-\log(1+3x^2-3x-x^3)=\log(1+x)^3-\log(1-x)^3=3[\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)]=3f(x)$$

Comment: You actually solved the problem lol (where's the hint ?).Thank you ;)

Comment: Sorry :) Bad tendency of mine. Start writing in order to give a hint and end up solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

hint $$log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=2(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}...\infty)$$ for $|x|<1$

Comment: I think the author of the problem didn't mean to use this,but thanks anyway.Also I would like to see how you would implement this hint in the problem to simplify it .

Comment: Oh okay  but condition of this series matches yours so thought would be sort of help.

Comment: It surely will help someone with more advanced math knowledge than mine since I haven't studied series but I was asking if you could show me how you would use that actually in the problem to get the answer.

Comment: So rather than going for log you just have to do algebra